# Virtual inheritance, default constructors and extra copying

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

If you look at the code below, you will see that there are classes `A`, `B` and `C` which each inherit from the last.  The inheritance is `virtual`, meaning that `C` has to call `A`'s constructor, even though it doesn't inherit directly from `A`.

This is all good and well, but there are two ways to handle this and they both seem hacky to me, so I'd like to know whether this really is how you are supposed to do it.

The first way (the code below as it is) appears to call `A::A(a)` twice, once in `B`'s constructor and then again in `C`'s constructor.  Of course it doesn't get constructed twice, but a side effect of this is that the parameter `a` gets copied an extra time, just so it can be passed to `B::B(a, b)` even though that function doesn't end up using the value.  It only needs the value to construct `A::A(a)`, but here that constructor is called from `C` instead, so the copy of `a` passed to `B::B(a, b)` is simply thrown away.

To avoid this wasted copy, the alternative is to create additional constructors in the base classes (uncomment the code below for this option.)  This avoids the wasted copy, however the drawback is that you as the programmer are creating an entirely new constructor for your classes, which is never actually called by the code at runtime.  You have to declare the function, implement it (even if it's empty) and actually write code that calls it, even though that code will never actually run!  This sort of thing normally signals a broken design somewhere, so I am wondering whether there is another way you are supposed to achieve this that is less dodgy.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Data {
    Data() {
        std::cout << "Creating data\n";
    }
    Data(const Data& d) {
        std::cout << "Copying data\n";
    }
};

struct A {
    A(Data a)
    {
        std::cout << "A(a)\n";
    }
/*
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A()\n";
    }
*/
};

struct B: virtual public A {
    B(Data a, Data b)
        :   A(a)
    {
        std::cout << "B(a, b)\n";
    }
/*
    B(Data b)
    {
        std::cout << "B(b)\n";
    }
*/
};

struct C: virtual public B {
    C(Data a, Data b, Data c)
        :   A(a),
            B(a, b)
/*
            B(b)
*/
    {
        std::cout << "C(a, b, c)\n";
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Data a, b, c;
    std::cout << "-- B --\n";
    B bb(a, b);
    std::cout << "-- C --\n";
    C cc(a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, a few people have made the comment that I should just pass by reference.  Ignoring the fact that this isn't always what you want (think smart pointers), it doesn't remove the fact that you're passing a value to a function that never gets used, which seems dodgy.  So the choices are either pass a value that gets thrown away silently (and hope you never get bitten by that) or implement a function you will never call (and hope that never comes back to bite either.)

So my original question still stands - are these really the only two ways to do this?  You have to choose between a superfluous variable or a superfluous function?

Comment: Just pass arguments by reference.

Comment: hello Malvineous, I'm wondering why you're not accepting Mateusz's answer ?

Comment: @niceman Not everyone is patrolling the site at all times. The OP has 3k rep and 62 questions, most of them with an accepted answer. You can assuse they know how/when to accept.

Comment: @niceman I think I didn't hit the real problem the OP wants to solve.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, if that was your intention, but you are doing A LOT of unnecessary copies of `Data`, because every parameter is passed by value. That means, every time `A::A(a)` is called, new instance of `Data` is created, which is copy-constructed from `a` parameter. In `B::B(a,b)` two such copies are made and in `C::C(a,b,c)` - three copies. But note, that `B::B(a,b)` calls `A::A(a)` and `C::C(a,b,c)` calls `B::B(a,b)`, so I guess, that calling `C::C(a,b,c)` actually creates **six** copies of `Data`:

- **three** copies of `a`
- **two** copies of `b`
- **one** copy of `c`

You can avoid this, by passing constructor's arguments by reference - then, no copy is made, unless you, in constructor body or initialization list, will decide to make one.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Data {
    Data() {
        std::cout << "Creating data\n";
    }
    Data(const Data& d) {
        std::cout << "Copying data\n";
    }
};

struct A {
    A(const Data& a)
    {
        std::cout << "A(a)\n";
    }
/*
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A()\n";
    }
*/
};

struct B: virtual public A {
    B(const Data& a, const Data& b)
        :   A(a)
    {
        std::cout << "B(a, b)\n";
    }
/*
    B(Data b)
    {
        std::cout << "B(b)\n";
    }
*/
};

struct C: virtual public B {
    C(const Data& a, const Data& b, const Data& c)
        :   A(a),
            B(a, b)
/*
            B(b)
*/
    {
        std::cout << "C(a, b, c)\n";
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Data a, b, c;
    std::cout << "-- B --\n";
    B bb(a, b);
    std::cout << "-- C --\n";
    C cc(a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Creating data
Creating data
Creating data
-- B --
A(a)
B(a, b)
-- C --
A(a)
B(a, b)
C(a, b, c)
```

**EDIT:**

I see, that I misunderstood your problem. Now, I am not sure if I understand it at all. After compiling your original code:

[Output]

```
[Cut]
-- C --
Copying data // copy of c in C::C()
Copying data // copy of b in C::C()
Copying data // copy of a in C::C()
Copying data // copy of a passed to A::A()
A(a)
Copying data // copy of b passed to B::B()
Copying data // copy of a passed to B::B()
B(a, b)
C(a, b, c)
```

Now, which copies you want to get rid of?

You wrote, that `A::A()` is called twice - in `B::B()` and `C::C()`. But you create two objects, one of type `B` and one of type `C`. Both these types inherit from `A`, so `A::A()` will always be called - either explicitly or not. If you don't call `A::A()` explicitly, default constructor for `A` will be called. If it's not defined, compiler error will be generated (try to remove call to `B(a, b)` from `C::C()`).

Comment: Sorry perhaps I was unclear in my question.  I didn't pass by reference on purpose to make it clear that the copies were happening.  I've edited the question accordingly.  Even if you change it to use references as you have done in your code, you are still calling `B(a, b)` in the `C` constructor, yet that value of `a` is never used and thrown away.  What if it was an `std::unique_ptr` - you can't pass it to two different functions!

Comment: Sorry it is a bit difficult to explain exactly what I mean.  The copy I want to get rid of is `copy of a passed to B::B()` but the problem is not necessarily the copy itself, the copy is a manifestation of an underlying problem - namely `a` gets passed to both `A::A()` and `B::B()` when in fact only one of those constructors needs it.  But I have to pass it to both constructors, and one simply ignores it.  To me that looks like bad design, which makes me think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: But it's not a bad design, it's how C++ works. That's why we firstly focused on value passing - if you need to pass an object so 'deep', you cannot do this by value. Imagine, that you have a set of functions calls: `func_a(Data& d)` calls `func_b(Data& d)`, which calls `func_c(Data& d)`... and so on, let's say 8 levels of calling and each one of them passes object, that it received as parameter. Now, change these functions' prototypes, so they accept `d` by value. That's a bad design. Do you understand? It's your responsibility to ensure, that certain semantics for your custom types are valid,

Comment: [...] well defined and do not make heavy impact on performance. You gave an example of `std::unique_ptr` - this class doesn't define copy constructor, so you always have to pass it by reference. And if it was `std::shared_ptr` - so what? We would have one additional copy, that would be immediately destroyed after constructor exits. Cost of this copy is marginal (simple increment/decrement of ref counter), so there's no pain. You will always pay for everything, one way or another. Just make sure price isn't too high, when gain isn't worth it.

Comment: That's fair enough, and if that's the way it has to be, so be it. But if you forget about copies for a moment, you still have to pass an unused parameter. Even if you pass an `std::unique_ptr` by reference, which function do you pass it to? `A::A` or `B::B`? You have to look at the implementation for `B::B` and see that it does not use its `unique_ptr` parameter and then pass `nullptr` there instead.  Having to know what goes on inside an implementation seems to go against common wisdom about encapsulation. Of course if that's the way it is then so be it, but I only ask because it seems fishy.

Answer (score 1):

The way you use Virtual inheritance is wrong, and in this question - there is no relation between the "extra copies" and virtual inheritance

Virtual inheritance is done in order to solve the Diamond problem - if both Horse and Bird inherit from "Animal" , and Pegasus inherit both from Horse and Bird - we don't want every member variable in "Animal" to be contained twice .thus we inherit Horse and Bird virtually in order to have Animal Object only once in Pegasus.

here , this example doesn't present the diamond problem hence doesn't reflect any real use of virtual inheritance (other then it forces A ctor to be called first.)

also , the reason that there are so many copies is because you pass everything by value and not as const reference as you should. passing everything as references will elude most of the copies here.

Comment: The first two paragraphs are just wrong. The OP uses virtual inheritance, therefore there's virtual inheritance, period. Yes, VI is commonly used to prevent diamond issues, but whether inheritance is virtual or not depends solely on the `virtual` keyword being used. Diamond or no diamond has no effect on the inheritance virtuality.

Comment: of course the compiler compiles everything as virtual inheritance. the point is that conceptually , there is no relation between "the extra copies" and the fact that the inheritance is virtual , and also , I tries mentioning that this example doesn't use virtual inheritance as it should be used

Comment: I changed the answer a bit

Comment: I'd say it's not wrong, just unnecessary. But perhaps the OP just simplified an actual dimond-shaped use case.

Comment: That's exactly what I did.  I removed the fluff and chose not to pass by reference to illustrate the problem more easily, otherwise with a dozen classes all interacting I'd be posting too much code nobody would bother to read.